# What could cause moisture on my bonus room floor?

Tags: insulation, hardwood, condensation

Last week during a cold snap with high winds. I discovered moisture along the floor on one side of my bonus room, above the attached garage. Their was enough moisture that the baseboard molding buckled and pulled away from the wall. This occurred on the western facing wall. All other walls / floors were fine with no visible moisture.

I opened up the attic hatch to this area and saw plenty of insulation. Bats in the wall and blown in for the floor area.

I can't figure out what would be causing this, as the house is 2 months old.

Any ideas?

Comment: This sounds like the symptoms of an insufficient vapor barrier. Do you have anything between the conditioned space and the insulation to prevent humidity from getting into the insulation?

Comment: Depending on the amount and timing of the moisture, it could also be a leak from above or outside. Have you checked gutters, valleys in the roof line, flashing, grading of the nearby ground, or anywhere else that water could intrude.

Comment: I am with @BMitch - I would also worry that something might not have been caulked well.  Water, freezes, expands crack, moisture.

Comment: What was the lowest temperature of the garage during the cold spell?  Did you keep the garage door closed?